# I'm trying to install Kivy with Python 3.9.0 and it gives me an error after I type: python -m pip install kivy

Tags: pip, windows-10, kivy, python-3.9

I'm on Windows 10.
I was following the instructions on https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html# and I reached the part where it says:

Install Kivy:

```
python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
```

After I type it in cmd, it gives me an error. I'll put the error as a comment.

Comment: Don't put the error as an answer. [Edit] it into your question as formatted text.

Comment: I tried and it said that I entered more than 30,000 characters

Comment: Look at the error and try to find the "Traceback" part at the end, then put that in your question.

Comment: At any rate, I'm fairly certain what the error is. Go to Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy) repository and download the `.whl` file for your Python installation - 32 or 64 bit. Install it using `python -m pip install name-of-whl-file.whl` and you should be okay. If you get errors for other packages, try to find them on the same page.

Comment: We don't have 3.9 wheels for Kivy 1.11.1. Installing `kivy==2.0.0.rc3` _might_ work, but not sure if we've released 3.9 wheels for that either yet, we were waiting on some dependencies.

Comment: Try `pip install pipwin`, and then `pipwin install kivy==1.11.1`

Comment: @KetZoomer Thanks! It worked! I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much! I've been trying to to `pip install kivy` for so long! I never knew about `pipwin`

Comment: You can follow this video [Usando KivyMD com Python 3.9, Kivy 2.0.0 e a IDE VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297628/im-trying-to-install-kivy-with-python-3-9-0-and-it-gives-me-an-error-after-i-ty) steps, works to me! Regards.

Comment: tooo soon to switch to python 3.9, stay a while on python 3.8. Dependencies have to migrate and become stable before a Kivy wheel is released officially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try `pip install pipwin` and then `pipwin install kivy==1.11.1`

Credits to [@KetZoomer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297628/im-trying-to-install-kivy-with-python-3-9-0-and-it-gives-me-an-error-after-i-ty/64635479#comment113698808_64297628)

Answer (score 0):

try to install thanks to pip, type in a terminal:

`pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).